# Can't fit an imported excel table in a page (overfull hbox and vbox)

Tags: tables, tabularx, arrays, landscape, badness

Good evening to anyone. I'm trying desperately to fit this table into an horizontal page. As I've used excel2latex to import it, I'm using the `array` environment, and I don't really know what to do to make it fit... I tried to use `tabularx`, but I LaTeX cannot compile... The table seems too large and too tall...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{array}{l l l l l l l l l l l l}

    \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\
    Economic Analysis & Unit of Measure & BAU &  &  &  & \textbf{PROJECT} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     &  & 2024-2029**  &  & 2030-2041  &  & 2024-2025 &  & 2026-2029**  &  & 2030-2041  &  \\ \hline
     &  & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak \\ 
    Investment & € & 0 &  & 0 &  & 175 &  & 0 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    VOT  & €/h & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    Extra Delay  & h & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.17 & 0.33 & 0.17 \\ \hline
    Delay costs & € & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 3.33 & 1.67 & 3.33 & 1.67 \\ \hline
    A\&D Tourist & mln / year & 8 & 2 & 5.5 & 1.17 & 8 & 2 & 8.33 & 2.06 & 5.83 & 1.22 \\ \hline
    A\&D Locals  & mln / year & 2 & 3 & 1.875 & 2.75 & 2 & 3 & 2.07 & 3.07 & 1.89 & 2.77 \\ \hline
    TOTAL & mln / year & 10 & 5 & 7.36 & 3.92 & 10 & 5 & 10.4 & 5.12 & 7.72 & 3.99 \\ \hline
    Price Tourist & €/trip & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 & 160 & 120 & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 \\ \hline
    Elasticity (Tourist) &  & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    Res. Price (Tourist)  & €/trip & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 \\ \hline
    Price Locals & €/trip & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 & 40 & 30 & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 \\ \hline
    Elasticity (Locals)  &  & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\ \hline
    Res. Price (Locals)  & €/trip & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 \\ \hline
    Subsidy (€/trip)  & €/trip & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 \\ \hline
    Revenues (Tourist)  & mln € & 1280 & 240 & 880 & 140 & 1280 & 240 & 1333.33 & 246.67 & 933.33 & 146.67 \\ \hline
    Revenues (Locals) & mln € & 80 & 90 & 75 & 82.5 & 80 & 90 & 82.67 & 92 & 75.67 & 83 \\ \hline
    TOTAL REVENUES & mln € & 1690 &  & 1177.5 &  & 1690 &  & 1754.67 &  & 1238.67 &  \\ \hline
    CS (Tourist)  & mln € & 320 & 60 & 151.25 & 20.42 & 320 & 60 & 347.22 & 63.38 & 170.14 & 22.41 \\ \hline
    CS (Locals)  & mln € & 640 & 720 & 576.5625 & 625.625 & 640 & 720 & 664.78 & 738.56 & 584.84 & 631.72 \\ \hline
    TOTAL CS & mln € & 1740 &  & 1373.85 &  & 1740 &  & 1813.94 &  & 1409.11 &  \\ \hline
    GROSS WELFARE  & mln € & 3430 &  & 2551.35 &  & 3430 &  & 3568.6 &  & 2647.76 &  \\ \hline
    Permits 2030  & (€ / ton CO2 pas trip) & 50 &  &  &  & 50 &  &  &  & 50 &  \\ \hline
    Social Discount Rate &  & 0.05 &  &  &  & 0.05 &  &  &  & 0.05 &  \\ \hline
    Actual Permit Prices & / ton CO2 pas trip) & 37.31 &  &  &  & 37.31 &  &  &  & 37.31 &  \\ \hline
    Emissions & \text{ton $CO_2$ / pas trip} & 0.5 &  &  &  & 0.5 &  &  &  & 0.5 &  \\ \hline
    TOTAL EXTERNAL COSTS* & (€) (year) & 279.83 &  & 0 &  & 279.83 &  & 289.57 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    FLOW EXTERNAL COSTS* & (€) & 1678.98 &  & 0 &  & 559.66 &  & 1158.29 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    NPV & (€) & 31544.88 &  &  &  & 32223.96 &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    NET BENEFIT &  &  & 679.072 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  & \  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  \\ \hline
    IRR &  &  & 0.29 & \#NUM! &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  \\ \hline
\end{array}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

```
Overfull \hbox (307.39384pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 154--193
```

```
Overfull \vbox (129.3531pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []
```

Comment: Which column does the header "2030-2041" belong to? Does it only belong to column 5 or to column 5 and 6?  If the latter is the case, you could save some space by using `\multocolumn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs a `tabular` environment (actually, a `tabular*` environment) instead of an `array` environment, embeds the tabular material in a `sidewaystable` environment, takes some care to structure the header material, and uses few but well-spaced horizontal rules. No need to reduce the font size.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\linespread{1.3} % don't use the low-level macro '\linespread' directly
\usepackage{setspace}\setstretch{1.3}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate} % 'enumitem' package would be a better choice
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
%%\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{caption}
%%\usepackage{subfigure} % 'subfigure' is deprecated! 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs,mhchem,rotating} % <-- new
%%\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{hyperref} % load this package _last_

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{l} }
    \toprule
    Economic variable & Unit & \multicolumn{4}{c}{BAU} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{PROJECT} \\ 
    \cmidrule{3-6} \cmidrule{7-12}
     & &  \multicolumn{2}{c}{2024--2029**} & 
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{2030--2041}   & 
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{2024--2025}   & 
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{2026--2029**} &  
          \multicolumn{2}{c}{2030--2041}   \\ 
    \cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8} \cmidrule{9-10} \cmidrule{11-12}
    & &  Peak & O/P & Peak & O/P & Peak & O/P & Peak & O/P & Peak & O/P \\ 
    \midrule
    Investment   & €        & 0 & & 0 & & 175 & & 0 & & 0 &  \\ 
    VOT          & €/h      & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\ 
    Extra Delay  & h        & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.17 & 0.33 & 0.17 \\ 
    Delay costs  & €        & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 3.33 & 1.67 & 3.33 & 1.67 \\ 
    A\&D Tourist & mln/year & 8 & 2 & 5.5 & 1.17 & 8 & 2 & 8.33 & 2.06 & 5.83 & 1.22 \\ 
    A\&D Locals  & mln/year & 2 & 3 & 1.875 & 2.75 & 2 & 3 & 2.07 & 3.07 & 1.89 & 2.77 \\ 
    TOTAL        & mln/year & 10 & 5 & 7.36 & 3.92 & 10 & 5 & 10.4 & 5.12 & 7.72 & 3.99 \\ 
    Price Tourist& €/trip   & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 & 160 & 120 & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 \\ 
    Elasticity (Tourist) & -- & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ 
    Res. Price (Tourist)  & €/trip & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 \\ 
    Price Locals & €/trip & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 & 40 & 30 & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 \\ 
    Elasticity (Locals)  & -- & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\ 
    Res. Price (Locals)  & €/trip & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 \\ 
    Subsidy (€/trip)  & €/trip & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 \\ 
    Revenues (Tourist)  & mln € & 1280 & 240 & 880 & 140 & 1280 & 240 & 1333.33 & 246.67 & 933.33 & 146.67 \\ 
    Revenues (Locals) & mln € & 80 & 90 & 75 & 82.5 & 80 & 90 & 82.67 & 92 & 75.67 & 83 \\ 
    TOTAL REVENUES & mln € & 1690 & & 1177.5 & & 1690 & & 1754.67 & & 1238.67 &  \\ 
    CS (Tourist)   & mln € & 320 & 60 & 151.25 & 20.42 & 320 & 60 & 347.22 & 63.38 & 170.14 & 22.41 \\ 
    CS (Locals)    & mln € & 640 & 720 & 576.5625 & 625.625 & 640 & 720 & 664.78 & 738.56 & 584.84 & 631.72 \\ 
    TOTAL CS       & mln € & 1740 & & 1373.85 & & 1740 & & 1813.94 & & 1409.11 &  \\ 
    GROSS WELFARE  & mln € & 3430 & & 2551.35 & & 3430 & & 3568.6 & & 2647.76 &  \\ 
    Permits 2030   & €/ton \ce{CO2} pas trip & 50 & &  & & 50 & &  & & 50 &  \\ 
    Social Discount Rate & & 0.05 & &  & & 0.05 & &  & & 0.05 &  \\ 
    Actual Permit Prices &/ton \ce{CO2} pas trip & 37.31 & &  & & 37.31 & &  & & 37.31 &  \\ 
    Emissions      & ton \ce{CO2}/pas trip & 0.5 & &  & & 0.5 & &  & & 0.5 &  \\ 
    \addlinespace
    TOTAL EXT. COSTS* & € (year) & 279.83 & & 0 & & 279.83 & & 289.57 & & 0 &  \\ 
    FLOW EXT. COSTS* & € & 1678.98 & & 0 & & 559.66 & & 1158.29 & & 0 &  \\ 
    NPV & € & 31544.88 & &  & & 32223.96   \\ 
    NET BENEFIT & &  & 679.072 \\ 
    IRR & &  & 0.29 & \#NUM!  \\ 
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow... Thank you really... Too kind... I'm speechless...

Answer (score 1):

First I added `booktabs`, always useful for better row spacing and rules, and `pdflscape` to be able to see the landscape table horizontally in the monitor, for easier debugging. The font size is `\small`, the rows stretched by `\arraystretch` from the `array` package. I added some `multicolumns` to center the second row over Peak / Off-Peack and centered most columns for better viewing.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[margin=1.2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\RequirePackage{pdflscape} % added  
\RequirePackage{booktabs} % added

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
    \small
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3} %% added  
    
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c c c c c}

%    \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\
\toprule
    Economic Analysis & Unit of Measure  BAU &\multicolumn{10}{c}{\textbf{PROJECT}} \\ 
    \toprule
     &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2024-2029**}   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2030-2041 } & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2024-2025} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2026-2029**}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2030-2041} \\ \hline      
     &  & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak \\ \midrule
    Investment & € & 0 &  & 0 &  & 175 &  & 0 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    VOT  & €/h & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    Extra Delay  & h & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.17 & 0.33 & 0.17 \\ \hline
    Delay costs & € & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 3.33 & 1.67 & 3.33 & 1.67 \\ \hline
    A\&D Tourist & mln / year & 8 & 2 & 5.5 & 1.17 & 8 & 2 & 8.33 & 2.06 & 5.83 & 1.22 \\ \hline
    A\&D Locals  & mln / year & 2 & 3 & 1.875 & 2.75 & 2 & 3 & 2.07 & 3.07 & 1.89 & 2.77 \\ \hline
    TOTAL & mln / year & 10 & 5 & 7.36 & 3.92 & 10 & 5 & 10.4 & 5.12 & 7.72 & 3.99 \\ \hline
    Price Tourist & €/trip & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 & 160 & 120 & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 \\ \hline
    Elasticity (Tourist) &  & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    Res. Price (Tourist)  & €/trip & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 \\ \hline
    Price Locals & €/trip & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 & 40 & 30 & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 \\ \hline
    Elasticity (Locals)  &  & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\ \hline
    Res. Price (Locals)  & €/trip & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 \\ \hline
    Subsidy (€/trip)  & €/trip & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 \\ \hline
    Revenues (Tourist)  & mln € & 1280 & 240 & 880 & 140 & 1280 & 240 & 1333.33 & 246.67 & 933.33 & 146.67 \\ \hline
    Revenues (Locals) & mln € & 80 & 90 & 75 & 82.5 & 80 & 90 & 82.67 & 92 & 75.67 & 83 \\ \hline
    TOTAL REVENUES & mln € & 1690 &  & 1177.5 &  & 1690 &  & 1754.67 &  & 1238.67 &  \\ \hline
    CS (Tourist)  & mln € & 320 & 60 & 151.25 & 20.42 & 320 & 60 & 347.22 & 63.38 & 170.14 & 22.41 \\ \hline
    CS (Locals)  & mln € & 640 & 720 & 576.5625 & 625.625 & 640 & 720 & 664.78 & 738.56 & 584.84 & 631.72 \\ \hline
    TOTAL CS & mln € & 1740 &  & 1373.85 &  & 1740 &  & 1813.94 &  & 1409.11 &  \\ \hline
    GROSS WELFARE  & mln € & 3430 &  & 2551.35 &  & 3430 &  & 3568.6 &  & 2647.76 &  \\ \hline
    Permits 2030  & (€ / ton CO2 pas trip) & 50 &  &  &  & 50 &  &  &  & 50 &  \\ \hline
    Social Discount Rate &  & 0.05 &  &  &  & 0.05 &  &  &  & 0.05 &  \\ \hline
    Actual Permit Prices & / ton CO2 pas trip) & 37.31 &  &  &  & 37.31 &  &  &  & 37.31 &  \\ \hline
    Emissions & \text{ton $CO_2$ / pas trip} & 0.5 &  &  &  & 0.5 &  &  &  & 0.5 &  \\ \hline
    TOTAL EXTERNAL COSTS* & (€) (year) & 279.83 &  & 0 &  & 279.83 &  & 289.57 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    FLOW EXTERNAL COSTS* & (€) & 1678.98 &  & 0 &  & 559.66 &  & 1158.29 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    NPV & (€) & 31544.88 &  &  &  & 32223.96 &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    NET BENEFIT &  &  & 679.072 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  & \  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  \\ \hline
    IRR &  &  & 0.29 & \#NUM! &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were using the `array` environment outside math mode. Also, there was a conflict concerning the `url` package. I have also reduced the font size. This will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\linespread{1.3}
\usepackage[margin=1.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}
\usepackage{color,soul}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}\tiny
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l l l l l l l l}

    \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\
    Economic Analysis & Unit of Measure & BAU &  &  &  & \textbf{PROJECT} &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     &  & 2024-2029**  &  & 2030-2041  &  & 2024-2025 &  & 2026-2029**  &  & 2030-2041  &  \\ \hline
     &  & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak & Peak & Off-Peak \\ 
    Investment & € & 0 &  & 0 &  & 175 &  & 0 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    VOT  & €/h & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 & 10 \\ \hline
    Extra Delay  & h & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.67 & 0.33 & 0.33 & 0.17 & 0.33 & 0.17 \\ \hline
    Delay costs & € & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 6.67 & 3.33 & 3.33 & 1.67 & 3.33 & 1.67 \\ \hline
    A\&D Tourist & mln / year & 8 & 2 & 5.5 & 1.17 & 8 & 2 & 8.33 & 2.06 & 5.83 & 1.22 \\ \hline
    A\&D Locals  & mln / year & 2 & 3 & 1.875 & 2.75 & 2 & 3 & 2.07 & 3.07 & 1.89 & 2.77 \\ \hline
    TOTAL & mln / year & 10 & 5 & 7.36 & 3.92 & 10 & 5 & 10.4 & 5.12 & 7.72 & 3.99 \\ \hline
    Price Tourist & €/trip & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 & 160 & 120 & 160 & 120 & 185 & 145 \\ \hline
    Elasticity (Tourist) &  & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 \\ \hline
    Res. Price (Tourist)  & €/trip & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 & 240 & 180 \\ \hline
    Price Locals & €/trip & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 & 40 & 30 & 40 & 30 & 65 & 55 \\ \hline
    Elasticity (Locals)  &  & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 & 0.4 \\ \hline
    Res. Price (Locals)  & €/trip & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 & 560 & 420 \\ \hline
    Subsidy (€/trip)  & €/trip & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 & 120 & 90 \\ \hline
    Revenues (Tourist)  & mln € & 1280 & 240 & 880 & 140 & 1280 & 240 & 1333.33 & 246.67 & 933.33 & 146.67 \\ \hline
    Revenues (Locals) & mln € & 80 & 90 & 75 & 82.5 & 80 & 90 & 82.67 & 92 & 75.67 & 83 \\ \hline
    TOTAL REVENUES & mln € & 1690 &  & 1177.5 &  & 1690 &  & 1754.67 &  & 1238.67 &  \\ \hline
    CS (Tourist)  & mln € & 320 & 60 & 151.25 & 20.42 & 320 & 60 & 347.22 & 63.38 & 170.14 & 22.41 \\ \hline
    CS (Locals)  & mln € & 640 & 720 & 576.5625 & 625.625 & 640 & 720 & 664.78 & 738.56 & 584.84 & 631.72 \\ \hline
    TOTAL CS & mln € & 1740 &  & 1373.85 &  & 1740 &  & 1813.94 &  & 1409.11 &  \\ \hline
    GROSS WELFARE  & mln € & 3430 &  & 2551.35 &  & 3430 &  & 3568.6 &  & 2647.76 &  \\ \hline
    Permits 2030  & (€ / ton CO2 pas trip) & 50 &  &  &  & 50 &  &  &  & 50 &  \\ \hline
    Social Discount Rate &  & 0.05 &  &  &  & 0.05 &  &  &  & 0.05 &  \\ \hline
    Actual Permit Prices & / ton CO2 pas trip) & 37.31 &  &  &  & 37.31 &  &  &  & 37.31 &  \\ \hline
    Emissions & \text{ton $CO_2$ / pas trip} & 0.5 &  &  &  & 0.5 &  &  &  & 0.5 &  \\ \hline
    TOTAL EXTERNAL COSTS* & (€) (year) & 279.83 &  & 0 &  & 279.83 &  & 289.57 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    FLOW EXTERNAL COSTS* & (€) & 1678.98 &  & 0 &  & 559.66 &  & 1158.29 &  & 0 &  \\ \hline
    NPV & (€) & 31544.88 &  &  &  & 32223.96 &  &  &  &  &  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  & \  \\ \hline
    NET BENEFIT &  &  & 679.072 &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  & \  \\ \hline
     &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  \\ \hline
    IRR &  &  & 0.29 & \#NUM! &  &  &  &  &  &  & \  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}


\end{document}
```